# Self signed ssl certificate for Remote Desktop Gateway not working

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl-certificate, remote-desktop-gateway

I have configured Remote Desktop Services role in a windows 2008r2 server and applied a self-signed SSL certificate. I also installed the same certificate in a client machine and tried to connect to the Remote Desktop Gateway. But then an error pops up saying the requested RD server address doesn't match with the subject name given in the certificate. When I viewed the certificate pointed by the error message, it is a different one than the one that I installed.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you follow proper steps to install the certificate? Like, for example, [these](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/install-ssl-certificate-on-remote-desktop-gateway-server)?